# failure running a simple MapReduce Streaming job with MR1 CDH4

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have a cluster that had running CDH4 upgraded recently from CDH3. Hive is currently working pretty good. However I can t seem to make it run even simple MR Streaming jobs (version 1). Yarn is installed but not in use.
Here is the command line input and output

```
$ /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-  streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0.jar grep -input /input -output /output/ 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

Checking the logs reveals this:

```
packageJobJar: [/tmp/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-unjar7491355516546899751/] [] /tmp/streamjob1375201380112960182.jar tmpDir=null
12/07/12 07:26:29 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/07/12 07:26:29 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [file:////data/hadoop-0.20/cache/mapred/mapred/local]
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201207120604_0018
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob: UNDEF/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=frost:54311 -kill job_201207120604_0018
12/07/12 07:26:29 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: >http://alpha:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201207120604_0018
12/07/12 07:26:30 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
12/07/12 07:26:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
12/07/12 07:26:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
12/07/12 07:26:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: UNDEF/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=frost:54311 -kill job_201207120604_0018
12/07/12 07:26:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: >http://alpha:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201207120604_0018
12/07/12 07:26:57 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: NA
12/07/12 07:26:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!
```

Logs output a lot of failings reduce tasks:

```
2012-07-12 07:26:46,785 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201207120604_0018_m_000001_2: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:861)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.map(IdentityMapper.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you look in the generated job.xml for your submitted job (via the JobTracker web interface), and see what the defined values for the mapper is? (`mapreduce.map.class` property).

From the map logs you included, it looks like you may have the identity mapper configured (hence the LongWritable coming out as the output Key, rather than the job defined value of Text):

> Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

If this is the case, you'd need to look into the Streaming code for 2.0.0 hadoop (which i don't have immediately to hand), to see how launching the `hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0.jar` jar with you arguments will configure and run a job

Comment: Thanks Chris. I first tried setting the following property into mapred-site.xml <property>

<name>mapred.input.format.class</name>

<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat</value>

</property> but it didn t work. However the two following properties saved the day:<property>

<name>stream.map.input</name>

<value>typedbytes</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>stream.reduce.input</name>

<value>typedbytes</value>

</property>